# || in Ruby - Unexpected Keyword End

Tags: ruby

I figure I am missing something trivial but for some reason this code doesn't work and gives an unexpected keyword end error:

```
if @quote.user.email.include? "test" || @quote.user.email.include? "test2"
    email = ""
else
    email = @quote.user.email
end
```

However, this works if I wrap each statement in parenthesis like this.

```
if (@quote.user.email.include? "test") || (@quote.user.email.include? "test2")
    email = ""
else
    email = @quote.user.email
end
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: Because operator precedence matters.

Comment: This would have also worked (and been the right approach): `@quote.user.email.include?('test') || @quote.user.email.include?('test2')`

Comment: Can you elaborate how this effects the execution? I'm more familiar with Java and this type of syntax would work as expected there.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That makes sense.

Comment: @CannonMoyer: "and this type of syntax would work as expected there" - no, it wouldn't. Last I checked, java doesn't have parenthesesless method calls (didn't check java 8, tho)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I see, I just didn't realize I had to add the parenthesis on the method call for Ruby.

Comment: @CannonMoyer: to remove ambiguity, you have to use parens. When there's no ambiguity, you're free to omit them.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Makes sense. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: You only have to check for `@quote.user.email.include? "test"`, the check for `"test2"` is redundant. (unless your actual values are different)

Comment: @Stefan Good catch, but the values are different. It's checking for two different domain names in production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the compiler cant tell what you're trying to do.

```
@quote.user.email.include? "test" || @quote.user.email.include? "test2"
```

is very ambiguous, and so the compiler tries to figure out what this means.

```
@quote.user.email.include?("test") || @quote.user.email.include?("test2")
@quote.user.email.include?("test" || @quote.user.email.include?) "test2"
@quote.user.email.include?("test" || @quote.user.email.include?("test2"))
(@quote.user.email.include? "test") || (@quote.user.email.include? "test2")
```

in this case, the compiler grants preference to the `or` operator, which is the second case. this is not valid syntax, and consequently throws an error

leaving off parens (seattle style syntax) is convenient, but sometimes it gets too ambiguous, and you need to use them

i'd recommend adding parens to the method arguments

```
@quote.user.email.include?("test") || @quote.user.email.include?("test2")
```

Comment: The above operator isn't `or`. Actually, there wouldn't be any SyntaxError with `or`. It doesn't mean it should be used, though.

Comment: seattle style syntax --- lol. You have particular company/group of people in mind?

Comment: @Stefan I see. Didn't know that.

Comment: i didnt come up with the name 'seattle style', thats just what its called lol